# Why is this line infinite loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code for reading a file worked and completed instantly.

```
auto copy = [&](const FileName &src, std::ofstream &dst)
{
    std::ifstream r(src);
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(r, line)) { dst << line << std::endl; }
};
```

`src` is a small file, `dst` is a working output stream. If I changed the loop to:

```
while (std::getline(std::ifstream(src), line)) { dst << line << std::endl; }
```

My program was running forever in the while loop. Why infinite looping? I'm using Xcode C++11.

Comment: You could output line. For me it looks a bit as if You are only reading the first line all the time,because you seem to create always a new ifstream therefore no pointer/iterator is kept and set to any next line.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because everytime you call `std::getline` in while loop, new `std::ifstream(src)` will be initialized and you always get the first line of the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (std::getline(std::ifstream(src), line)) { dst << line << std::endl; }
```

Because you initialize the stream in every loop run.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because the function`getline(stream, string)` takes the first line in the stream. When you do `ifstream(src)` you are creating a new stream and starting from the beginning.

Hope this helps